# How to get always the newest current Coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, distance

I am trying to calculate the distance between your current location and three markers.
Everything is working fine, but if I change my position the distance is equal to the distance before, I dont get the new coordinates. Here is my code:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
   LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
   Location current = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));
   latng = String.valueOf(current.getLatitude());
   lngon = String.valueOf(current.getLongitude());
   Location club = new Location("clubloc");
   club.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(marker_data.get("lat")));
   club.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(marker_data.get("lng")));
   double distance = current.distanceTo(club);
   distance = distance / 1000;
   distance = Math.round(distance * 100);
   distance = distance / 100;
   TextView dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
   dis.setText(String.valueOf(distance) + "KM");
  }
```

So my question is how can I update my coordinates so I always get the right distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always getting the last known location of the user (using `getLastKnownLocation`). You are not actively asking for location updates. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).

Comment: Thanks bro i solved it using the onLocationChanged method